# Is it possible to execute a formula inside a variable?

Tags: excel, vba

I want to know if it is possible in VBA to use the content of a variable as "code". For example:

```
x = 23

formula= "43,025*X^-0,452"

Value = ExecuteContentOf(formula)
```

I have used a power curve in excel to calculate the formula that represents the best curve for 4 different x,y values. 
(1,40) (7, 20) (30,10) (60,6)

The result is a graphic with the formula inside. Excel calculate that automatically. Using VBA I can extract the text of the formula from the  object title.

The result us is = 43,025*C2^-0,452

Now I want to use it myself in VBA changing C2 for other variable (not a cell), so y= 43,025*x^-0,452.
As the formula is in a string.. 
Is it possible to tell VBA to interpret it?

I'm looking for the same functionality as the EVAL function on Javascript

Comment: This can be done by making the formula a public function instead.

Comment: Do you need this to be appicable to different formulas or just this specific formula? @Plutian's solution is probably the most elegant, and applicable to both cases.

Comment: I'm looking for the same behaviour as Eval function on Javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is unclear whether you need to pull the formula from the object title at runtime, or whether you can hard code it.

Hard coding it would be trivial. `Application.Evaluate` will give you very similar functionality to the EVAL function in Javascript.

```
x = 23
formula= "43,025*" & x & "^-0,452"
Value = Application.Evaluate(formula)
```

However, if you want to get the formula on the fly at runtime, that is a separate issue as you will need to find the range reference in the string and replace it with your new variable. If it is the same reference every time. That would be quite simple.

I will leave this task up to you. If you need help, please clarify your exact requirements and I will update my answer.

Comment: @hammet No problem. Glad I could help.

Answer (score 0):

The following function and sub calling that function inserts your formula into a cell with a specified range as the argument. You can set this to any cell.

```
Sub evaluate()
Dim x As Range
Dim blah As String
Set x = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A2")
blah = Formulaz(x)
Range("A3").Formula = blah
End Sub

Public Function Formulaz(x As Range)
Formulaz = "=43.025 *" & x.Address & "^-0.452"
End Function
```

To change this to take a string instead you can simply amend like so:

```
Dim x As String
Dim blah As String
x = Range("A2").Value
blah = Formulaz(x)
Range("A3").Formula = blah
End Sub

Public Function Formulaz(x As String)
Formulaz = "=43.025 *" & x & "^-0.452"
End Function
```

This yields the same result (the formula being inserted in a cell and the solution showing) but it takes the value of a cell as argument.

As OP stated this is not what is needed, perhaps this works better:

```
Sub evaluate()
Dim x As String
Dim blah As String
x = "5"
blah = Formulaz(x)
Debug.print blah
End Sub

Public Function Formulaz(x As String)
Formulaz = 43.025 * x ^ -0.452
End Function
```

It returns the value of the expression with x passed as the argument. The output for x = 5 will be 20.78674 stored in Blah as a string.

Comment: That is not what I need, sorry.

Comment: @hammet Can you elaborate? It does what you stated you need in your question. This method can easily be adapted for different outputs and inputs.

Comment: @hammet answer updated with a closer approximation to what you asked. If this is still not what you need, consider editing your question.